# advanced search page for web application using vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-applications, search, advanced-search

i created a simple advanced search page for web application, i thought sharing it with you might help beginners

the following is an example of an advanced search page for an employee database using VB.Net

[image]

the following is the code behind page

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class searchme
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mydb As New OleDbConnection
    mydb = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= |datadirectory|employee.mdb;Persist Security Info=True")
    mydb.Open()

    Dim sqlstring = "select * from [dataview] where "

    If MRNTextBox1.Text <> "" Then sqlstring = sqlstring + "[code] like '%" + CodeNameTextBox1.Text + "%' OR [EmployeeName] like '%" + CodeNameTextBox1.Text + "%' AND "


    If GOVDDL.SelectedItem.Text <> "--Please Select--" Then sqlstring = sqlstring + "[Governorate] ='" + GOVDDL.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND "
    If genderddl.SelectedItem.Text <> "--Please Select--" Then sqlstring = sqlstring + "[Gender] ='" + genderddl.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND "
    If DateEmploymentFrom.Text <> "" And DateEmploymentTo.Text <> "" Then sqlstring = sqlstring + "[DateEmployment] >= #" + DatumKonvert1.DK1(DateEmploymentFrom.Text) + "# AND [Datepresentation] <= #" + DatumKonvert1.DK1(DateEmploymentTo.Text) + "# AND "
    If DepartmentDDL.SelectedItem.Text <> "--Please Select--" Then sqlstring = sqlstring + "[Department] ='" + DepartmentDDL.SelectedItem.Text + "' AND "


    sqlstring = Left(sqlstring, Len(sqlstring) - 5) + " order by " + OrderByDDL.SelectedItem.Text


    Dim myds As New AccessDataSource
    myds.DataFile = "~\App_Data\employee.mdb"
    myds.SelectCommand = sqlstring


    ' Dim Mygrid As New GridView

    Mygrid.DataSource = myds

    Mygrid.DataBind()


    ' Me.form1.Controls.Add(Mygrid)


    mydb.Close()

    RecCount.Text = "Filtered Record Count = " + mygrid.Rows.Count.ToString
    Session("dsource") = myds
    Response.Redirect("sresults.aspx")


End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: what's the problem with this?

Comment: there isn't, just wanted to share

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did a good job, also try the following

[link text](http://www.beansoftware.com/Demo_Search_Control.aspx)

[link text](http://www.asp101.com/samples/db_search_aspx.asp)